# Setting up a Github Commit RSS feed

Tags: github, rss, feed, github-api, atom-feed

I am trying to have my github commits as an RSS feed but so far I have not managed to figure it out. I know that a private feed is available with the following syntax:

```
https://github.com/username.atom?token=token
```

But this the user's activity feed. I would like a commit feed of one of my projects.

Update: This was the final syntax:

```
https://github.com/username/repository_name/commits/branch_name.atom?login=login&token=token.
```

Still can't view commits on all branches though.

Comment: to view commits on all branches try: `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/commits.atom` the issue is that you are giving an specific branch name in your example

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You want `https://github.com/whatever/commits/master.atom`, like for the [Cloudera flume repository](https://github.com/cloudera/flume) it's `https://github.com/cloudera/flume/commits/master.atom`.

Comment: Thank you very much CanSpice. I forgot to mention it is a private repository. Could you please post that example? Also, is there a way for the rss to post from many branches?

Comment: I'd imagine that it follows the same pattern. Substitute your repository name for `whatever` and put `?token=token` on the end. Give that a shot.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question showing the final syntax. However i havent been able to view the commits on all branches

Comment: Did you try `master.atom` instead of `branch_name.atom`?

Comment: I did, it just gets the commits for my "master" branch

Comment: Is there a way to get a feed of tags for a project?  Certain projects use tags to provide release tarballs.  It would be useful to follow these as an RSS feed.

Comment: @TrinitronX - You can replace commits/master.atom with releases.atom to get the releases.
So for the example above, it would be https://github.com/cloudera/flume/releases.atom.

Comment: I think private repos need to go through the webhooks.

Comment: Please note, that Outlook 2010 x64 has issues reading RSS ATOM feeds. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/cannot-add-atom-rss-feed-in-outlook-2010-x64-bit/329645c4-fd91-4f56-b222-bf527b3b3da9?auth=1.

Comment: @cynistersix may be correct, as I have just tested between a public and private repository at `.../commits.atom`.  The public one returns an XML document with entries, while the private one simply responds with `Not Found`.  Also noting that the private one is under an organization that I have access to.  Tested through my web browser, so they are simply GET requests.  I would be curious if anyone can provide more specific information about any WebHooks for GitHub repository RSS feeds.

Comment: You can also get feed for history of a particular file: `https://github.com/whatever/commits/master/path/to/file.atom`.

Comment: @FranklinYu Thanks so much for this Franklin!  Where did you get the doco for this? Or did you just figure it out yourself?  Does anyone know if there's a way to modify that file commits url so the RSS would include the diff fragments instead of just the comment?

Comment: @Shorn I just figured out the URL myself, so I don't know how to show diff in feed. Sorry.

Comment: There's a a link to the commit as part of the Atom entry, so it's either one click away (or gesture in mobile app) - so I'm happy with how it is.  Thanks again!

Comment: @CanSpice It is nice to see the answer helped many people. It does not address the `Still can't view commits on all branches though.` aspect of the question yet. Nor does it appear to show a feed of all commits in a repository. Instead, it shows (all) the commits in a specific branch of a repository (As pointed out by @jalagrange).

Answer (score 22):

There is another alternative **[RssHub](https://docs.rsshub.app/en/)** except the [official atoms](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds/) (first part).

> GitHub provides some official RSS feeds officially:
>
> Repo releases: https://github.com/:owner/:repo/releases.atom
>
> Repo commits: https://github.com/:owner/:repo/commits.atom
>
> User activities:
> https://github.com/:user.atom
>
> Private feed:
> https://github.com/:user.private.atom?token=:secret (You can find
> Subscribe to your news feed in dashboard page after login)

**RssHub:**

### Github repositories

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/repos/yanglr

Routing: `/github/repos/:user`

parameters:

- User(required): username

### Github Trending by Language

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/trending/daily/javascript

Routing: `/github/trending/:since/:language?`

parameter:

- Since (required): Time span, available in the [Trending page](https://github.com/trending/javascript?since=monthly) URL, optional daily monthly
- Language (optional)

  Language, which can be found in the [Trending page](https://github.com/trending/javascript?since=monthly) URL

### Github Repository  Issues

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/issue/DIYgod/RSSHub

Routing: `/github/issue/:user/:repo`

parameter:

- User (required ):   username
- Repo (required ): repository name

### Github Repository Pull Requests

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/pull/DIYgod/RSSHub

Routing: `/github/pull/:user/:repo`

parameter:

- User (required): username
- Repo (required): repository name

### Github User

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/user/followers/yanglr

Routing: `/github/user/followers/:user`

parameter:

- User (required):  username

### Github Repository Stars

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/stars/yanglr/CaliburnMicro-Calculator

Routing: `/github/stars/:user/:repo`

parameter:

- User  (required):   username
- Repo (required):   repository name

### Github Search results

Example: https://rsshub.app/github/search/RSSHub/bestmatch/desc

Routing: `/github/search/:query/:sort?/:order?`

parameter:

- Query (required):  search keyword
- Sort (optional):  Sorting options (default is bestmatch)
- Order (optional):   Sort order, desc and asc (default desc descending)

[image]

Besides, you can use [Feed43](https://www.feed43.com/users.html?action=new) to create feed for any web page if unnecessary to login with account. Official tutorial, click [here](http://feed43.com/step-by-step.html) to view.

Comment: Commits for a repository's wiki: `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/wiki.atom`