Get email notification when someone pushes
For a repository on GitHub that I don't own, but where I am a collaborator, how can I get an email notification every time someone pushes a commit to the repository? For repositories that I own, I can enable this in Settings / Email notifications. But for repositories that I don't own, I have no "Settings" button.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600376/14201841

Watch the GitHub repository. Make sure email notifications are allowed on your account.
Im not even a collaborator of this one repository and I get notified on stuff. If what I said doesn't work Ill go through my settings again and try to update this.


Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Under Settings / Notifications, my "Default notifications email" is set correctly. Under Subscriptions / Watching, Email notifications are on. And I'm watching the repository in question, and Notifications are on for "All Activities"...
