# How can I access a GitHub private project RSS feed?

Tags: github, rss, atom-feed

Is it possible to read activity of a GitHub private repository and of its branches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seting up Github Commit RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353538/seting-up-github-commit-rss-feed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, just follow these steps:

1. In your browser, login to your private repository on GitHub.
2. Select the branch you are interested in.
3. Click on the Commits tab.
4. You will find a RSS icon next to the words "Commit History".
5. Copy the link or click the icon to add the URL to your feedreader.

Comment: I didn't see the RSS icon, so it's probably been removed?
Instead I got the link by searching for  atom  in the HTML source code of the page. A browser plugin/extension could also work, while taking the webpage's link into a RSS reader would work for public but not for private repositories (since it would first have to login to github).

Comment: @SimonB. has the new correct answer. The RSS links are on longer visible on the page, but they can be found easily by searching source of a branch's page (http://github.com/[user_or_org]/[repo]/tree/[branch]) for "atom".

Comment: @jmorganmartin is 100% correct here and that should be the new answer to this question. Private hub repo feed found that way by viewing the repo branch in the browser, view source, and search for atom, use that href link as the feed and poof! it works

Answer (score 7):

Note that [since July 2013](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-07-01-feeds-api/), you can list GitHub feeds through the [Feeds API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds/), but:

> Private feeds are only returned when [authenticating via Basic Auth](http://developer.github.com/v3/#basic-authentication) since current feed URIs use the older, non revokable auth tokens.