# GitHub website: pin a non-master branch on the dashboard

Tags: github

We use GitHub for our project and are happy with it. 
I often browse the project website to check what my friends are doing on the project, and the dashboard lists the last commits on the master branch of all repositories I contribute to.

This is well and nice, but most of the work happens on other branches then get merged.

Any idea how to pin what happens to these branches on the dashboard?

Comment: i don't know if this is what you want, but you can change the "Default branch" in your repository settings: http://cl.ly/image/3n0N0M3v2a1I

Answer (score 0):

Beside changing the default branch of a GitHub repo (which isn't what you need), you could also set an RSS feed: see "[Setting up an Github Commit RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353586/6309)"

```
https://github.com/username/repository_name/commits/branch_name.atom?login=login&token=token
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was hoping to tweak the dashboard.

Comment: @Jean-Yves no, nothing from the dashboard directly.