# Revoke / Generate Github personal news RSS feed token

Tags: github, rss

I accidentally leaked it. I searched the Github docs and account settings but did not find anything to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to regenerate a new [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), and invalidate/remove the previous one in your  to access your `Settings / Developer Settings /  Personal access tokens / Tokens (classics)` section.

Then you should be able to test your RSS feeds, knowning that, as the [Feed API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/feeds) page mentions:

> Private feeds are only returned when [authenticating via Basic Auth (`USERNAME:TOKEN`)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication) since current feed URIs use the older, non revocable auth tokens.

You can list your feeds with

```bash
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/feeds
```

Or use thrid-part GitHub feed generators like [RSSHub](https://docs.rsshub.app/en/) (as [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369953/6309)).

Comment: I see, so if I exposed my token for the private RSS feed then there is nothing I can do...

Comment: @Kallzvx Yes, as I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/6309), a token is made to be revoked at any time (as opposed to a password, which is trickier to change).